# VS2005 stucks on Build Started phase for 5-10 mins. Only happens when I change a build configuration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

VS2005 stucks on "Build Started ..." %first project name here% step for 5-10 mins. Only happens when I change a build configuration. Only happens to one solution.

Deleting a %first project% in a solution didn't help - i would just stuck on any first compilable project.

I have disabled the intellisense, installed every possible hotfix and still no luck.

Any ideas how to track down the cause of that initial delay please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a very good idea to take a minidump and/or check what visual studio is doing by using Process monitor -> threads -> stack/ This is most likely to provide the exact and fast answer.